# Route KeyUpEvent from UIElement to a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, uielement

How do I route the `KeyUpEvent` event for a `UIElement` to a `TextBox` in WPF?

For example with the following objects:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangleWPF"></Rectangle>
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxWPF"></TextBox>
```

If an 'A' is pressed on **rectangleWPF** then an 'A' must be inserted into **textBoxWPF**.  Then if a backspace is pressed on **rectangleWPF**, **textBoxWPF** should display nothing.

Comment: maybe you need to change the example... why adding a handler to rectangleWPF.PreviewKeyUp() with the logic for txtBoxWpf doesn't work for you? You want the Rectangle.KeyUp to fire TextBox.KeyUp?

Answer (score 0):

Think simple:  in your event handler for the `UIElement`, just test to see which key is pressed.  If it's alphanumeric, add it to the `textBoxWPF.Text` property.  If it's a backspace, make the `textBoxWPF.Text` property a substring of itself, minus the last character.  If it's something else you don't want (or don't handle), ignore it.

There's no reason to implement some magic to reroute events when something simple will work better.